# Value of keys when no unique value is present

Tags: reactjs

I have an infoBox component in React that needs to be used multiple times.

- I have an array of objects.
- Each value of the object needs to be passed to the infoBox component leading to the creation of an infoBox.

I am achieving this is by iterating over the object array using map(). I am able to get the output, but I was getting logs in console for unique keys.

Since my object does not have any unique value, I tried using Math.random(). Is it the right approach?

What value do I give for keys, when I do not have unique values in my objects?

```js
userDetails = [{name : "Raj", place : "Chennai"}, {name : "Rani", place : "Mumbai"}, {name : "John", place : "Bengaluru"}]

userDetails.map((user){
    return (<InfoBox details = user>);
});
```

Edit :

userDetails is populated dynamically say based on an organization. When the organization changes, the entire array of objects will be replaced by a new one.

Eg:

```
userDetails = [{name : "Tom", place : "New York"}, {name : "Pip", place : "Colombo"}, {name : "Davis", place : "Dubai"}]
```

Comment: Can the `userDetails` array ever change?

Comment: yes. It could change based on the other inputs in the page.

Comment: Please post the code showing how exactly it can change - it matters a lot.

Comment: There still is not enough information about how the `userDetails` can change to provide an informative answer - please post the code that changes `userDetails` if you want one

Answer (score -1):

When you don't have the keys of your object, You can use the index of your loop then doesn't show any warning. It's worked.

Comment: https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c

pls do check this. It is not a good idea to use the index.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate the id with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
userDetails.map((user) => <InfoBox details = {user} key = {userDetails.indexOf(user)}/>)
```

Comment: When we use index, it will lead to problems as the entire array could be changed and an entirely different object can take the same key. This will lead to discrepancies.